# How do we select a random row from a mysql result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE code LIKE '$querywc'";    
$res=mysql_query($qry);
```

this code fetches the rows based on the wildcards specified in the variable $querywc
i'm sure that it'll return many rows.
now what i want is, a random row from those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order randomly and use `limit` to take just one row

```sql
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE code = '$querywc'
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster to execute :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM `users` WHERE code LIKE '$querywc' order by rand();
```